# Knockoutjs Prevent subscription loop

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

My view model manually subscribes to an observable so that when it is changed, the value is validated via AJAX. then if the value is invalid, it is changed to a default value.

The problem is the validation gets done twice because of the subscription: when user changes the value to an invalid one and when the view model change the value to fix it.

What is an elegant way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [extenders documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html).  Extenders allow you to do exactly this kind of interception.  You'd use the extender rather than the subscription.